# How do I stop my menu going mobile if it fits in the menu area on the device?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

On my website I've got a little code which makes my menu turn "mobile" if the device screen res is smaller than 1024px - My menu would still display correctly even if the device is around 800px, so is there a way to do that - or should I just suck it up and leave it as 1024px?

My site is [here](http://totally.tech/onovsut)

I'm not sure if its going to be css or js where I need to start looking at the code.

Can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Please, can you past your code here, also it will be great to add a JSFiddle.

Comment: Is that piece of code all CSS or Javascript? And yes, please provide a JSFiffle.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that pretty easily. You should see somewhere in your CSS the following line followed by some CSS rules that will be applied when the screen is less than 1024.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px)
```

You can adjust that to 800px and you're good to go!